# MongoDB controlled transaction abort

Tags: mongodb, transactions, mongo-go

I worked with mongo driver for golang, but possibly that question is actual for other implementations.

Do mongo driver always abort transaction in case errors? Can I prevent implicit abort for transactions?

For example, for such code, I always get `err2 = (NoSuchTransaction) Transaction 7 has been aborted.` if `err1!= nil`.

```
    client := ir.Source.Client()
    session, err := client.StartSession()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := session.StartTransaction(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err = mongo.WithSession(ctx, session, func(sc mongo.SessionContext) error {

        _, err1 := ir.Source.Collection(collectionName).UpdateOne(sc,
            bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: bid}},
            bson.M{
                "$set": bson.D{{Key: "name", Value: "Name"}},
            },
        )
        if err1 != nil {
            log.Println(err1) // I don`t want abort here
        }
        _, err2 = ir.Source.Collection("collectionName").UpdateOne(sc,
            bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: bid}},
            bson.M{
                "$set": bson.D{{Key: "name", Value: "Name"}},
            },
        )
        if err2 != nil {
            log.Println(err2) 
            sc.AbortTransaction(sc) // i want abort only here
        }
        return sc.CommitTransaction(sc)
     }); err!=nil {
  return err
}
```

Can I use some options for transactions or rewrite code, so I will control transactions abort by myself?

Comment: What is err1???

Comment: err1 is error of first statement in transaction.

Comment: Yes, what is it?